# Base64 string encoding contains +, / and = instead of A, B, C

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

I need to apply the following transformation to a string:

- convert the string in byte[]
- apply the sha256 function
- encode the result in base64

I wrote the following code:

```
string codeRaw = "C0643778W.EUC06AG978W.EUFWELP2014-11-2153.50000GBP24.00000MWh/h10YCB-EUROPEU--12015-01-012015-01-31";
byte[] utiCodeByteArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeRaw);
byte[] hashByteArr = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(utiCodeByteArr);
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashByteArr)
```

It works, but the result is a little bit different from was I should get: the string contains the chars '+', '/' and '=' instead of 'A', 'B' and 'C'.

```
"qWAIh1CgYAuvoRTGcvXKLBHC9UxRunSBRjRXlqhYh6gC" //expected result
"qW+Ih1CgYAuvoRTGcvXKLBHC9UxRunS/RjRXlqhYh6g=" //got result
```

I've solved with a replace

```
 string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashByteArr)?.Replace("+", "A")?.Replace("/", "B")?.Replace("=", "C");
```

There is a better way to get the right string without using the replaces?
I don't like them.

The manual with the requirements say: "The APIs used are the ones provided by .NET framework", but it doesn't contains the source code: maybe there is a way to get immediately the ABC chars, but I miss it.

Thanks.

Comment: "the result is a little bit different from was I should get" How did you figure out what you should get?

Comment: The manual say that using the .NET API I should have got that result (there are some examples of source strings with the expected results).

Anyway, as I say, I don't know if there is really a way to get the ABC chars. But the sentence "The APIs used are the ones provided by .NET framework" gave me that doubt

Comment: What makes you think base 64 strings only contain alpha characters (ABC etc)? From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx "The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase characters "A" to "Z", the lowercase characters "a" to "z", the numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/". The valueless character, "=", is used for trailing padding."

Comment: Ok: in such case, I'll leave the replaces :-) 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The provider sent me the source code: there was a replace as the one I did.

They forgot to wrote that information in the manual.